# Change the background color when listbox is disabled

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

I have a ListBox, and I want to change the background color when ListBox is disabled and Style variable is "Negative" or "Positive", Initial, I did as below:

//----------------------------UPDATED----------------------------

```
<ListBox>
    <ListBox.Style>
        <Style TargetType="{x:Type ListBox}">
            <Style.Triggers>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnable}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Style}" Value="Negative"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Black" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
                <MultiDataTrigger>
                    <MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding RelativeSource={RelativeSource Self}, Path=IsEnable}" Value="False"/>
                        <Condition Binding="{Binding Path=Style}" Value="Positive"/>
                    </MultiDataTrigger.Conditions>
                    <Setter Property="Background" Value="Yellow" />
                </MultiDataTrigger>
            </Style.Triggers>
        </Style>
    </ListBox.Style>
</ListBox>
```

But, not worked, ListBox can't change background color by above solution, so I did as below:
//----------------------------END UPDATED----------------------------

```
<StackPanel>
    <ListBox IsEnabled="{Binding ElementName=enabledButton, Path=IsChecked}">
        <ListBox.Resources>
            <SolidColorBrush x:Key="{x:Static SystemColors.ControlBrushKey}" Color="Red" />
        </ListBox.Resources>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 1</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 2</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 3</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 4</ListBoxItem>
        <ListBoxItem>Item 5</ListBoxItem>
    </ListBox>
    <ToggleButton Name="enabledButton" IsChecked="True" Content="IsEnabled"/>
</StackPanel>
```

It's work! ListBox can change background color to red when disabled.

But, I need add a condition:

-If style is negative (Style="Negative"), ListBox change color to "Black".

-If style is positive (Style="Positive"), ListBox change color to "Yellow".

I tried to use a trigger, but unsuccessful.
Anyone have a simple way to get this working?

Comment: What exactly do you mean by Style=Negative? Also you should post the code that actually changes the Background.

Comment: you can change template to change all colors if you want to.

Comment: @nuke Thank's for your reply, Style is a string variable. please review my updated question, may be clearer.
sorry for my bad english

Comment: @Đồng Hữu Quân Have you considered using a `MultiTrigger` instead of the `MutliDataTrigger`? Also the code you posted says `Path=IsEnable` which should probably be `Path=IsEnabled`. You might also look into using a `Converter` for your `Binding`.